# NLog: Count different events (Error, Info, etc.) and present the numbers as summary

Tags: .net, nlog

I would like to count NLog events like Error, Info, etc. and present the numbers in a summary (header/footer).
To determine a "session" I would like to use a BufferingWrapper. So if the Warpper is flushed, I'd like to present these numbers in the log target also:

*IE: 10 Errors, 12 Warnings, 44 Infos*

Is that possible without customizing NLog?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that if you will write your own TargetWrapper. See for example the 
[BufferingTargetWrapper.Write](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/blob/adbaa48840192b7065fb2f3bc1cbf62cd4116ac1/src/NLog/Targets/Wrappers/BufferingTargetWrapper.cs#L165-L186) and [the post on extending NLog](http://nlog-project.org/2015/06/30/extending-nlog-is-easy.html).